# Why is .push() creating arrays inside an array for me?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
    const bills = [124, 48, 268];
const tipAmount = [];
const totalPaid = [];

const tipCalc = (bill) => {
    let tip
    switch(true) {
        case(bill < 50 ):
            tip = bill*0.2;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
        case(bill > 50 && bill < 200):
            tip = bill*0.15;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
        case(bill > 200):
            tip = bill*0.1;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
    }
};

tipAmount.push(bills.map(el => tipCalc(el)));

console.log(tipAmount[0]);

const totalCalc = (thething) => {

    let onArray = bills.indexOf(thething);
    let result = Number(bills[onArray]) + Number(tipAmount[0][onArray]);
    return result;
};

totalPaid.push(bills.map( el => totalCalc(el)));

console.log(totalPaid[0]);
```

So first of all, this code works right now and I am well aware that I went for an overkill, I just wanted to try working with 2 arrays and stuff and now I'm trying to figure out why this is happening...

when I do `tipAmount.push(bills.map(el => tipCalc(el)));` an array inside the tipAmount array gets created and to further access the data I've put in tipAmount I have to do tipAmount[0][i], I'm trying to understand why this is happening and what I would have needed to have done to access this data simply by doing tipAmount[i]

thank you in advance

Comment: `.map(...)` returns an array, that's why.

Comment: because `map` returns an array

Comment: Simply push the totalCalc onto the array, since `map` returns an array `totalPaid.push(totalCalc(el));`

Comment: @B001ᛦ on here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push when it pushes 'cow' into the animals array, push doesn't create an array inside the animals array, it simply just adds 'cow' into there, I expect push to do the same for me and instead of what it's doing right now I expect it to simply add the returned numbers into the empty array

Comment: @ISAE aw that's right, i got it, i got it ... i shouldve used concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to go through javascript array map method, map will returns a new array.
when you do

```
tipAmount.push(bills.map(el => tipCalc(el)))
```

it will push a new array returned by bills.map function.
just spread new array into the push method,

```
    tipAmount.push(...bills.map(el => tipCalc(el)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing arrays into `tipAmount` with `tipAmount.push(bills.map(...))`. `bills.map` *returns* an array (a mapped version of itself), so `tipAmount` ends up being an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
const bills = [124, 48, 268];
var tipAmount = [];
var totalPaid = [];

const tipCalc = (bill) => {
    let tip
    switch(true) {
        case(bill < 50 ):
            tip = bill*0.2;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
        case(bill > 50 && bill < 200):
            tip = bill*0.15;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
        case(bill > 200):
            tip = bill*0.1;
            console.log(tip);
            return tip;
    }
};

tipAmount = tipAmount.concat(bills.map(el => tipCalc(el)));

console.log(tipAmount);

const totalCalc = (thething) => {

    let onArray = bills.indexOf(thething);
    let result = Number(bills[onArray]) + Number(tipAmount[onArray]);
    return result;
};

totalPaid = totalPaid.concat(bills.map( el => totalCalc(el)));

console.log(totalPaid);
```